# Enable command line completion of *.md files for firefox in konsole

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, firefox, konsole

When opening files in Firefox from konsole, the autocomplete function only works for certain file extensions like html, htm and the like. For other extensions, I have to type out the full name instead.

How can I configure firefox (or konsole) to give me the same behavior for other files? Specifically I'm asking for md files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the shell you are using. For example for `bash` you will find completion functions inside the `/etc/bash_completion.d` directory. You probably have one regarding `firefox` listing the extensions it looks after, and you should change it to add your `.md` extension.